# std::map find key pair and interpolate value

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have sets of data where one integer is mapped to another e.g. like this

```
std::map<int,int> IE   = { { -10, 85 }, { 0, 89 }, { 10, 92 }, { 20, 94 }, { 30, 98 } };
```

What I want to do is the following: given any integer as input value I want to find the pair of keys from the map that surround it and then do a simple interpolation (and then cast to int) between the values. An example:

```
input: 25
surrounding keys: 20, 30
surrounding values: 94, 98
interpolated: 96
```

Special cases: if the value is below the first key, return the first value, if the value is beyond the last key, return the last value.

Now, the best code I could come up with after some thinking is this:

```
int interpolatedValue( int value, const std::map<int,int> &map )
{
  // if we have exactly this value in the map, just return it                                                                                                                                                                 
  if( map.find(value) != map.end() ) return map.at(value);
  // if we are beyond the limits, return the first/last element                                                                                                                                                               
  if( value < map.begin()->first )   return map.begin()->second;
  if( value > map.rbegin()->first )  return map.rbegin()->second;

  auto lower = map.lower_bound(value) == map.begin() ? map.begin() : --( map.lower_bound(value)) ;
  auto upper = map.upper_bound(value);

  return int( lower->second + (upper->second - lower->second) * float(value-lower->first)/fabs(upper->first-lower->first) );

}
```

which is doing what I want but seems like an atrocity given such a simple task. Is there an obvious, more elegant way of doing this (or more correct in case I missed a corner case)? 
Also: is there a method of map that I missed that allows to find the pair of keys as described?

N.B. The code I posted is using c++11 features, but this is not at all a requirement so I am not including the tag.

Comment: The only thing I see missing is a test to make sure the map isn't empty. You can optimize a bit by calling `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` only once. And there's no need to use `find`, it's a special case that's handled by the interpolation just fine.

Comment: This is probably better suited on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You might be able to get the lookup down to one `equal_range`, but algorithmically speaking this isn't a huge improvement.

Comment: @BillLynch initially my question was -- I felt -- better suited here as I was under the impression that I was doing something silly and overlooked e.g. a feature of std::map or another stl container that would make this task much easier. Given the comments so far it seems that there is nothing completely stupid in what I wrote and I could indeed post things on codereview for improvement, even if there were already some hints for improvements here.